# How to add Array as string in Core Data in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-data

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to add NSArray in Core Data as an NSString.

I am using code like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
//Converting array as an string...
AuditIDCoreData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",idAuditarray];
AuditnameCoreData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nameAuditarray];

NSError *error;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Get_Auditnames_User" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

//  NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"Result =%@",results);

NSString *Stringaudit =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",idAuditarray];

ComplareArray=[devices valueForKey:@"auditname"];
ComplareArray2=[devices valueForKey:@"auditid"];

BOOL contains = [ComplareArray2 containsObject:Stringaudit];

if(contains == YES)
{
}
else
{
    if (self.device) {
        // Update existing device
        [self.device setValue:AuditIDCoreData forKey:@"auditid"];
        [self.device setValue:AuditnameCoreData forKey:@"auditname"];
    } else {
        // Create a new device
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Get_Auditnames_User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        //  NSLog(@"context",newDevice);
        [newDevice setValue:AuditIDCoreData forKey:@"auditid"];
        [newDevice setValue:AuditnameCoreData forKey:@"auditname"];
    }

    //NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Code I have Updated:

```
NSString *FailString =@"";
NSString *WarningString =@"";

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

for (int i = 0; i < idarray.count; i++){
    if (self.device) {
        // Update existing device
        [device setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
        [device setValue:Passarray[i] forKey:@"checklistid"];
        [device setValue:CheckpointNameIDArray[i] forKey:@"checkpointid"];
        [device setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
        [device setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
        [device setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
        [device setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
        [device setValue:imageArray[i] forKey:@"auditimage"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        } 
    } else {
        // Create a new device
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newDevice setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
        [newDevice setValue:Passarray[i] forKey:@"checklistid"];
        [newDevice setValue:CheckpointNameIDArray[i] forKey:@"checkpointid"];
        [newDevice setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
        [newDevice setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
        [newDevice setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
        [newDevice setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
        [newDevice setValue:imageArray[i] forKey:@"auditimage"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }           
    }
}
```

But it saves whole array in just a single string. I need to store array element one by one in Core Data as String.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do in just simple steps.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newData;
for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++){
    newData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"yourEntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newData setValue:array1[i] forKey:@"sub-entities"];    
    [newData setValue:array2[i] forKey:@"sub-entities"];        
}

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}else {
    NSLog(@"Data saved successfully ..");
}
```

Saving multiple array `array1` & `array2` to the sub-entities of an entity.

Comment: crash showing error 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "checklistid"; desired type = NSString; given type = __NSCFNumber; value = 97.

Comment: Please see the updated Question I have try your code but it get crash.

Comment: you are passing number whereas you database needs string there. Just convert you array to string using code `[newData setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array[i]] forKey:@"sub-entities"]; `

Comment: welcome, keep in remind that explicit conversion is not a prefered way just use original types.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it as follow

```
NSArray *arrayToBeConvertedInToString = @[@"This", @"is", @"an", @"array"];
NSString * result = [[arrayToBeConvertedInToString valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"Array in string: %@", result);
```

Comment: I am already doing this it sore whole array in just single string. I need to add array element one by one in core data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method explained by Richard G

**I ll suggest you to convert it into NSData and store it as transferable in coreData**

Converting into NSData

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayName];
```

Storing into CoreData

```
[newManagedObject setValue:nsData forKey:@"auditid"];
```

Be sure you have changed datatype to transformable in coredata